# how to hide outer border of rich:fileupload

Tags: css, file-upload

I want to hide border of rich:fileupload.I just need to show only browse button.Can anyone please guide me on this.

```
<td colspan="4">
            <rich:fileUpload  id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}" maxFilesQuantity="#{fileUploadBean.uploadsAvailable}" 
                acceptedTypes="txt,ppt,jpg,doc,xls, gif, bmp,pdf"  ontyperejected="alert('Only TXT,PPT,DOC,XLS JPG, GIF,PDF and BMP files are accepted');"
                addControlLabel="Browse" listHeight="auto" listWidth="300px"   onsizerejected="fileSizeRejected();" 
                immediateUpload="#{fileUploadBean.autoUpload}"  allowFlash="#{fileUploadBean.useFlash}"  addButtonClass="browse-button-font" >
                <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="uploadInfo" oncomplete="setFlag();"/>
            </rich:fileUpload>
            </td>
```

Below is my CSS code:
Even I put border:none still one border is coming outside the browse button.

```
    .rich-fileupload-button-border{
     border:none !important;
    }

    .rich-fileupload-ico-start,.rich-fileupload-ico-stop,.rich-fileupload-ico-clear,.rich-fileupload-anc{
    display: none !important;  
    } 

    .rich-fileupload-ico-add{
     border: 1px solid #474747; background: #0035a9 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_60_0035a9_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; 
    position: fixed;
    margin-right: .1em; text-decoration: none !important; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; zoom: 1; overflow: visible;
    background-image: none;
    }

    .browse-button-font
    {
    font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.0em;font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;     
    }

.rich-fileupload-toolbar-decor {  
 background: none;  
 border:none !important; 
}  

.rich-fileupload-list-decor{
border:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div div.rf-fu { border: 0px; width: 85px; !important }
div div.rf-fu-hdr { border: 0px; !important }
span span.rf-fu-btn-clr { border: 0px; !important }
span.rf-fu-btns-lft{ width: 85px; !important }
span.rf-fu-btns-rgh{ display: none; !important }
div div.rf-fu-lst { display:none; !important }
```

Try the CSS above, this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have tried above CSS but still one outer border is displaying outside Browse button.

Comment: Please provide some CSS / HTML so I can check :)

Comment: I have added css code.Kindly check and let me know if you found anything :)